ORA-22905 SQL_MACRO Table
I get an error when I call a function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_funct(v_var VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 SQL_MACRO IS
BEGIN
   RETURN q'{SELECT DUMMY FROM DUAL WHERE DUMMY = v_var}';
END;
/

SELECT * FROM test_funct('X');

ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
Oracle version 19c

Your code is correct, but SQL table macros do not work until version 19.7 according to the documentation.
Typically, new Oracle features are introduced with a major release number. Occasionally, as in this case, a feature is added in a Release Update.

Is there an alternative code ?

@AleksRous There probably is an alternative using some other dynamic SQL trick such as polymorphic table functions or Oracle Data Cartridge, but those alternatives will be more complicated. The answer depends on exactly what you're trying to accomplish, and what context you're trying to solve it in (does the problem need to be solved entirely in pure SQL, or can you return the results in a reference cursor to an application?) Edit your question, or ask a new question, and maybe we can find an alternate solution. I assume the current example is not the real problem you care about.

In Oracle you can select only from a table, not from function.
You have to cast an expression onto a table using TABLE keyword.
SELECT * FROM TABLE(test_funct('X'));

But actually you will also have change return type of the function, to return array of ROWS. Oracle SQL is strongly typed, you can not return "just some string"
CREATE TYPE t_tf_row AS OBJECT (
  id           NUMBER,
  description  VARCHAR2(50)
);
/

CREATE TYPE t_tf_tab IS TABLE OF t_tf_row;
/

-- Build the table function itself.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_tab_tf (p_rows IN NUMBER) RETURN t_tf_tab AS
  l_tab  t_tf_tab := t_tf_tab();
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. p_rows LOOP
    l_tab.extend;
    l_tab(l_tab.last) := t_tf_row(i, 'Description for ' || i);
  END LOOP;

  RETURN l_tab;
END;
/

-- Test it.
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(get_tab_tf(10))
ORDER BY id DESC;

Other option is to use producer-consumer pattern(in case of huge data volume). PIPELINE function
-- Build a pipelined table function.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_tab_ptf (p_rows IN NUMBER) RETURN t_tf_tab PIPELINED AS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. p_rows LOOP
    PIPE ROW(t_tf_row(i, 'Description for ' || i));   
  END LOOP;

  RETURN;
END;
/

-- Test it.
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(get_tab_ptf(10))
ORDER BY id DESC;


I still get the error ORA-22905 , My Oracle version 19.0

It's work for 19.9 but not work for 19.3
